# why the javascript function is not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a object `dom` which have a property named `changeCss` which changes the css on any element: the code is as follows:

```
var Dom = {
 changeCss : function(element, properties){
            if(typeof (properties) === "object"){

                var properties_name = Object.keys(properties),
                     properties_value = [];

             for ( var i = 0; i < properties_name.length ; i++  ){
                 var a = properties_name[i],
                  b = properties[a];

                  properties_value[i] = b;

                  element.setAttribute("style", a+":" + b+";");

             };

            }else{
                throw 'properties of '+ element +" should be object";  
            }   
        },  
}
```

so from this code you will be understand how i want to change the css of any element,and this is working perfectly. But the problem which i am facing is that if i am writing this code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("some_html_tag_id");
Dom.changeCss(x, {"width": "100px", "height":"80px"});
```

then the style element only consist `height:80px` not `width:100px` ! how to add all these style properties?

thanks

anni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all replace

```
element.setAttribute
```

with

```
element.style[a]= b;
```

But basically you should understand that YOU do. 
SetAttribute function set's new value to attribute style.
So 
    while i==0
    style='width:100px;'
    while i==1
    style= 'height:80px;'

because you just override value. If you want to keep SetAttribute function in your code. You need to concat all the values first, and then use set attribute

Answer (score 1):

In the DOM. The `style` attribute is not a string. It's an object. Which means you should do this instead:

```
element.style.setProperty(a,b);
```

However, older versions of IE doesn't support `setProperty` for style objects. So, even though the above is technically the standards compliant way of doing it, the guaranteed cross-borwser method that works is:

```
element.style[a] = b;
```

Note that for every instance where you think you need `setProperty` or `setAttribute`, the `object[x] = y` syntax will also work and in the case of styles is always backwards compliant (not to mention requires less typing).

Comment: It should work except for older versions of IE which doesn't support setAttribute for style objects.

Comment: When talking about cross-browser methods, maybe it's good to mention, that FF requires camel-cased property name when using `element.style[a] = ...`, other browsers accept both camel-cased and hyphen form.